# Payment in WordPress website

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, paypal, payment

I'm currently working on a WordPress website,
The Website broker between two users :

- The first user wants service and paid for this.
- The second user provides this service then takes money.
- The Website broker between users and takes a percentage of this
  money.

But stopped when I met a problem and can't find a solution,
I can easily deduct from the visa held by first user but do not know how to pay cash for the second user?!

Is there any way to transfer money to the second user, are easy and online because it will be almost daily ??

Comment: What's wrong with Paypal?

Comment: Maybe Bitcoin, then?

Comment: Can I transfer from my account to any other bank?